# Quicksight problem with custom aggregations and calculated fields

Tags: amazon-athena, amazon-quicksight

Here is my Drop-off Rate function

```
coalesce(1 - ({cnt}/{Lag}),1)
```

And the calculated field {Lag} is

```
lag(sum(cnt),[step ASC],1)
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
Custom aggregations can't contain both aggregated and nonaggregated fields.
```

Actually {Lag} no needs to be a sum of {cnt} bu the function requires it to be an aggregate.

Is there any workaround to achieve that drop-off calculation?

Answer (score 0):

You need to aggregate the cnt in the numerator as well.

coalesce(1 - (sum({cnt})/{Lag}),1)